# Strange stacktrace in analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, motorola

can someone explain me the following stacktrace?

```
Thread: main, Message: File res/drawable/zz_moto_list_bkg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1080417
Stacktrace: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/zz_moto_list_bkg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1080417
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1735)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:200)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownListView.<init>(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1578)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.buildDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1330)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1182
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1060)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1043)
at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3859)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:890)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:648)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.addLayer(LayerDrawable.java:186)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:157)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:795)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:736)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1732) ... 16 more
```

I can find this causing a force close multiple times in my analytics and only motorola devices seem to be affected. Its not one of my resources.

Any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance